# Реализовать алгоритм BFS

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Помогите реализовать поиск в ширину по графах
уже сделал DFS и DLS, а BFS уже не могу
вот это DFS

```
  class DepthFirstSearch
{
    private HashSet<Node> visited;
    private LinkedList<Node> path_DFS;
    private Node goal;
    public LinkedList<Node> DFS(Node start, Node goal)
    {
        visited = new HashSet<Node>();
        path_DFS = new LinkedList<Node>();
        this.goal = goal;
        DFS(start);
        if (path_DFS.Count > 0)
        {
            path_DFS.AddFirst(start);
        }
        return path_DFS;
    }

    private bool DFS(Node node)
    {
        node.Handler();
        if (node == goal)
        {
            return true;
        }
        visited.Add(node);
        foreach (var child in node.Children.Where(x => !visited.Contains(x)))
        {
            if (DFS(child))
            {
                path_DFS.AddFirst(child);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    internal object DFS(Node n06, Node n10, int v)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Program

```
class Node
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public List<Node> Children { get; }

    public Node(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Children = new List<Node>();
    }

    public Node AddChildren(Node node, bool bidirect = true)
    {
        Children.Add(node);
        if (bidirect)
        {
            node.Children.Add(this);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void Handler()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"visited {this.Name}");
    }
}
```

Вся програма здесь
https://gitlab.com/Sat228/bfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В DFS у Вас `LinkedList` работает как стек - в начало вставляете, с начала же и обходите.

А если использовать его, как очередь - вставлять в конец вместо `AddFirst`, то получится BFS

Comment: Можете показать как это сделать, у меня не выходить.

Comment: Замените AddFirst на AddLast

Comment: bfs виходить - это dfs только задом наперед?

Comment: Реализация при использовании такого хранилища- да, а результат разные.

Comment: хм в результате dfs (у меня там города) выйшло так:
Тернополь - Хмельницк - Виницца - Бердичев - Житомир -  Киев - Б.Церковь - Полтава - Харков это типо                     
var search_DFS = new DepthFirstSearch();
var path_DFS = search_DFS.DFS(n09, n16);
PrintPath_DFS(path_DFS);

Comment: в bfs тоже самое                    var path_BFS = search_BFS.BFS(n09, n16);
                    PrintPath_BFS(path_BFS);
Выйшло просто задом наперед.
Это нормально?

Comment: нужно заменить AddFirst  на AddLast только в public LinkedList